# Компиляция Arduino скетча в CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, arduino, mingw, clion

Хочу собирать скетчи в Clion. Что сделал

1. Поставил Clion 2020.1
2. Поставил к нему Arduino [плагин](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11301-arduino-support)
3. Поставил MinGW
4. Установил Arduino SDK
5. Скачал дополнительную библиотеку [IRRemote](https://github.com/z3t0/Arduino-IRremote.git) и распаковал ее в Arduino\Libraries

Теперь пишу скетч

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
#include <IRremote.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(8, 9, 4, 5, 6, 7);
IRrecv recv(13);

void setup() {
}

void loop() {
}
```

и при компиляции получаю ошибку

> CMakeFiles/Controller.dir/Controller_controller.ino.cpp.obj: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0`:
> D:/Arduino/Controller/controller.ino:25: undefined reference to `IRrecv::IRrecv(int)`
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Arduino Studio этот скетч отлично компилирует.

Содержимое CMakeList.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/ArduinoToolchain.cmake)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(PROJECT_NAME Controller)

set(${PROJECT_NAME}_BOARD uno)
project(${PROJECT_NAME})

# Define additional source and header files or default arduino sketch files
# set(${PROJECT_NAME}_SRCS)
# set(${PROJECT_NAME}_HDRS)

### Additional static libraries to include in the target.
# set(${PROJECT_NAME}_LIBS)

### Main sketch file
set(${PROJECT_NAME}_SKETCH controller.ino)

set(${PROJECT_NAME}_PORT COM4)

generate_arduino_firmware(${PROJECT_NAME})


print_board_list()
print_programmer_list()
```

Смущает меня еще вывод компилятора

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2020.1\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build D:\Arduino\Controller\cmake-build-debug --target Controller-upload -- -j 2
Scanning dependencies of target uno_CORE
[  6%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/uno_CORE.dir/C_/Program_Files_(x86)/Arduino/hardware/arduino/avr/cores/arduino/HardwareSerial.cpp.obj
......................
[ 83%] Linking CXX static library libuno_CORE.a
[ 83%] Built target uno_CORE
Scanning dependencies of target uno_LiquidCrystal
[ 86%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/uno_LiquidCrystal.dir/C_/Program_Files_(x86)/Arduino/libraries/LiquidCrystal/src/LiquidCrystal.cpp.obj
[ 90%] Linking CXX static library libuno_LiquidCrystal.a
[ 90%] Built target uno_LiquidCrystal
Scanning dependencies of target Controller
[ 93%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/Controller.dir/Controller_controller.ino.cpp.obj
[ 96%] Linking CXX executable Controller.elf
```

А где

```
Scanning dependencies of target uno_IRRemote
```

?

Comment: https://github.com/queezythegreat/arduino-cmake

Comment: @dIm0n и чем он лучше, идущего в стандартной поставке clion? Если убрать использование IRRemote то все компилируется

Comment: Такое ощущение, что где-то хранится список библиотек и просто распаковать библиотеку в папку `libraries` недостаточно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я был прав. Все дело в предопределенном списке библиотек. А хранится он в файле `.\cmake\Platform\Arduino.cmake` в таком виде

```
# For known libraries can list recurse here
set(Wire_RECURSE True)
set(Ethernet_RECURSE True)
set(SD_RECURSE True)
set(Servo_RECURSE True)
set(SPI_RECURSE True)
set(SoftwareSerial_RECURSE True)
set(EEPROM_RECURSE True)
set(LiquidCrystal_RECURSE True)
set(TFT_RECURSE True)
set(WiFi_RECURSE True)
set(Robot_Control_RECURSE True)
```

я добавил туда строку

```
set(IRremote_RECURSE True)
```

и проект откомпилировался